# Mysterious Type Mismatch in Elm

Tags: user-interface, dictionary, types, elm

The following code is supposed to produce a button, which when pressed creates a box (and a button to remove the box on it)

```
import Graphics.Input
import Signal (..)
import Signal
import Mouse
import Text (Text, asText, plainText)
import Graphics.Element (..)
import Graphics.Collage (..)
import Color (..)
import List
import Dict

--                  x    y   id   |         id
type Event = Add (Float, Float, Int) | Remove (Int) | Maybe

makebox : Int -> Element
makebox id =
  let (w, h) = (30, 30)
  in flow down
    [ layers [plainText "aaaa", collage w h [square 30 |> filled red]]
    , button_remove id ]

add = Signal.channel (0,0,0)
remove = Signal.channel (0)

button_add x y = Graphics.Input.button (Signal.send add (x, y, 2)) "add a box"

button_remove id = Graphics.Input.button (Signal.send remove (id)) "remove me"

main =
  let update event =
    case event of
      Add (x, y, id)  ->  Dict.insert id ((x,y), ((makebox id)))
      Remove (id)     ->  Dict.remove id
      Maybe          ->  identity
  in Signal.map (\dict ->  flow down
                            [ button_add 10.0 20.0 --makes add & remove buttons
                            , collage 500 500 (List.map (\(Just ((x,y), makebox)) -> move (x,y) makebox)
                                                (Dict.values dict)) --draws the dict
                            ]) --map function argument
  (foldp update Dict.empty
    (merge
      (Add    <~ (Signal.subscribe add)) --pipes button channels into events
      (Remove <~ (Signal.subscribe remove)))) --map signal argument
```

However, it produces this type error:

```
Type mismatch between the following types on line 40, column 14 to 20:

   ((Int, Int))

   Maybe.Maybe

It is related to the following expression:

   update
```

I don't see where this error is coming from, where is the Maybe.Maybe being passed into `update`, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Find & replace the line with the `collage` call in `main` to this:

```
                            , collage 500 500 (List.map (\((x,y), makebox) -> move (x,y) (toForm makebox))
```

---

## Quick code cleanup

That's a lot of code. I had to change the style a little to understand, how it works. What I did was move a lot more functions to the top-level and give them type annotations. I also changed the `button_add`/`remove` to camelCase, because that's the standard Elm naming convention. This is the result:

```
import Graphics.Input
import Signal (..)
import Signal
import Mouse
import Text (Text, asText, plainText)
import Graphics.Element (..)
import Graphics.Collage (..)
import Color (..)
import List
import Dict

--                  x    y   id   |         id
type Event = Add (Float, Float, Int) | Remove (Int) | Maybe

type alias Model = Dict.Dict Int ((Float,Float), Element)

makebox : Int -> Element
makebox id =
  let (w, h) = (30, 30)
  in flow down
    [ layers [plainText "aaaa", collage w h [square 30 |> filled red]]
    , buttonRemove id ]

add : Signal.Channel (Float,Float,Int)
add = Signal.channel (0,0,0)

remove : Signal.Channel Int
remove = Signal.channel 0

buttonAdd : Float -> Float -> Element
buttonAdd x y = Graphics.Input.button (Signal.send add (x, y, 2)) "add a box"

buttonRemove : Int -> Element
buttonRemove id = Graphics.Input.button (Signal.send remove id) "remove me"

update : Event -> Model -> Model
update event =
  case event of
    Add (x, y, id)  ->  Dict.insert id ((x,y), makebox id)
    Remove (id)     ->  Dict.remove id
    Maybe           ->  identity

-- move' : Just ((Float,Float),Element) -> Form
move' (Just ((x,y), makebox)) = move (x,y) makebox

view : Model -> Element
view dict = 
  flow down
    [ buttonAdd 10.0 20.0 --makes add & remove buttons
    , collage 500 500 (List.map move' (Dict.values dict)) --draws the dict
    ]

input : Signal Event
input = merge
  (Add    <~ (Signal.subscribe add)) --pipes button channels into events
  (Remove <~ (Signal.subscribe remove))

model : Signal Model
model = foldp update Dict.empty input

main : Signal Element
main = view <~ model
```

We still get the same, not very helpful type error. But now it's on the `move'` function. I added the type signature I thought of in comments.

## The problem(s)

There are two problems in this piece of code:

1. `move'` takes an `Element` (among other things) and tries to `move` it, but `move` works on `Form`s. So that requires a call to `toForm`, before it works.
2. This is where the type error comes from: [`Dict.values`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.1.0/Dict#values) gives a list of values, not a list of `Just` values (of type `Maybe.Maybe`).

The solution is therefore a `move'` function like so:

```
move' : ((Float,Float), Element) -> Form
move' (a,b) = move a (toForm b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup and help, but this doesn't seem to have solved the error - just moved it to between lines 49 & 52. I am lost at how to deal with problem 2.

Comment: @user22723 are you sure? I check both the TL;DR solution and the cleaned up one before posting. Note that the cleaned up code above is not the fully working one, you need to replace the `move'` implementation with the one that I ended my answer with. Here's a compiling version: http://share-elm.com/sprout/54d5308ce4b05f9c59b259cc

Comment: oh, my bad! I didn't replace the line, oops.